# Reading multipart request results in Unexpected EOF error

Tags: go

Go version: 1.6.3 macos

I am trying to write an api to upload an apk file (several MB in most cases) to the server. Here is the client side code:

```
func syncApk(apkFile *os.File) {
    defer apkFile.Close()
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(&buffer)
    defer writer.Close()
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("apk", filepath.Base(apkFile.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error creating form file: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    size, err := io.Copy(part, apkFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error copying apk file data: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Copied %v bytes for uploading...\n", size)

    response, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8080/upload", writer.FormDataContentType(), &buffer)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error making POST request to sync apk: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Successfully uploaded apk file: %v\n", response.StatusCode)
}
```

Server code:

```
func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: ":8080",
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", doApkUpload)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func doApkUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, _, err := r.FormFile("apk")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error retrieving apk file: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error reading apk file content: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, string(data))
}
```

After I run the server on localhost I run client side code, I get:

```
Copied 1448401 bytes for uploading...
Successfully uploaded apk file: 200
```

It looks like the multipart file is written correctly. However I see this error on the server side:

```
Error retrieving apk file: unexpected EOF
```

Any idea where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to add `defer response.Body.Close()` after `http.Post` in client side code.

Comment: @putu You have right. I added the line but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error indicates that the reader expected more data after the end of the request body. That missing data is the trailing boundary end line written by the [multipart Close](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Writer.Close) method.

Call the Close method after writing all parts and before posting the form.

```
func syncApk(apkFile *os.File) {
    defer apkFile.Close()
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(&buffer)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("apk", filepath.Base(apkFile.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error creating form file: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    size, err := io.Copy(part, apkFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error copying apk file data: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Copied %v bytes for uploading...\n", size)
    writer.Close()
    response, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8080/upload", writer.FormDataContentType(), &buffer)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error making POST request to sync apk: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Clse()

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Successfully uploaded apk file: %v\n", response.StatusCode)
}
```

Comment: Ah! An explicit close, in the correct location, instead of a deferred close solved my own problem. Thank you!