# Golang multipart request with PDF file leads to Unexpected EOF error but works with PNG/JPG images

Tags: go, file-upload

I want to upload a PDF file via a Multipart request. My code works for uploading images. But when I try to upload a PDF at least in the second run I receive the error `Unexpected EOF`
There are several other questions asked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060735/golang-random-unexpected-eof-error-with-reading-multipart-part) (only one bad answer) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959180/reading-multipart-request-results-in-unexpected-eof-error), where I would have to install the `multipart` package to give it a try, which I'm pretty confident should be solvable just by the `net/http` package.

```golang
func UpdateItem(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()

    // Read multipart form
    log.Info("Request Content Length:", r.ContentLength)
    err = r.ParseMultipartForm(64 << 20)
    log.Info("Parsed Form Content Length:", r.ContentLength)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("UpdateItem: ParseMultipartForm failed ", err)
        utils.ErrorJSON(w, err, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    mForm := r.MultipartForm
    if mForm == nil {
        log.Error("UpdateItem: ", errors.New("invalid form"))
        utils.ErrorJSON(w, errors.New("invalid form"), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
...
```

When uploading a PDF instead of PNG or JPG this leads to

```bash
error   UpdateItem: ParseMultipartForm failed unexpected EOF
```

Note: My PDFs are very small and only like 4 to 10 MB big. This should not be the issue. Also logging the `r.ContentLength` gives me the same size every time.
Any help or improvements for the code would be very apprecciated!

Comment: The error indicates that multipart reader reached EOF before reading the end boundary.  Is the client creating a valid mutltipart body for the PDF?  What is that client?

Comment: Yes thanks for the hint! I've developed the same gut feeling already. The client is not that easy to detect for me since there is a lot of VueJS code around it but I will update the question once this is clear to me!

Comment: if you have access to the frontend in the browser, take a look at the network requests in the developer tools.  Should give you a vue-free, accurate view of the HTTP interaction